# VBA look up returns as False

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to learn VBA excel.

I have 2 tabs: Sheet1 and Sheet2:

In Sheet1, I have data from A1 to D6. I decided to make this range into a name "iJob". (='Sheet1'!$A$2:$D$6)

In Sheet2, there are data that I want to check in Sheet1.

When I put this on a  cell like in B2
"=vlookup(a2,iJob,4,0)" - it works and I get to check the value I need from Sheet1.

I wanted to incorporate this into VBA and here is my Code:

```
Dim Tab2 As String
Dim txt As String

With ActiveSheet
txt = Range("A2").Value
Tab2 = Range("A2").Formula ="=VLOOKUP(txt,iJob,4,0)"

End With

MsgBox Tab2
```

I'm having a result of "False" instead of the one I'm getting when I used in the cell

Edit: Corrected some refferences

Comment: where is `iJob` defined

Comment: With `x = y = z` you are performing a comparison (which is False) and then an assignment. Split this into two separate assignment statements.

Comment: `txt` and` iJob` are VBA variables, you can't pass it to sheet formula

Comment: iJob is in the excel workbook
iJob is a name: "Sheet1!$A$2:$D$6" is the value

Comment: Hi Andy G, i see. So do you i know any way how can i incorporate the vlookup??

Comment: TRY-  `Range("B2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$6,4,0)"`
    then  `Tab2 = Range("B2").Value`

Comment: It depends whether you are trying to write a formula into a cell using VBA, or use an Excel function in code to obtain a value. At the moment your code is a mixture of these approaches. Decide what you are trying to achieve with your code.

Comment: @AndyG, I'm trying to hold the result of vlookup to Tab2. "Use an excel function in code to obtain a value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is easier than you expect:**

```
Dim Tab2 As String
Dim txt As String

With ActiveSheet
    txt = .Range("A2").Value
    .Range("A2").Formula ="=VLOOKUP(" & txt & ",iJob,4,0)"
    Tab2 = .Range("A2").Value
    MsgBox Tab2
    ' or
    MsgBox .Range("A2").Value
End With
```

*Alternatively:*

```
txt = Evaluate("VLOOKUP(""" & txt & """, iJob, 4, 0)")  
MsgBox txt
```

*Oneliner:*

```
MsgBox Evaluate("VLOOKUP(""" & txt & """, iJob, 4, 0)")
```

*Another approach:*

```
Dim wsFunc As WorksheetFunction: Set wsFunc = Application.WorksheetFunction
MsgBox wsFunc.VLookup(txt, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("iJob"), 4, False)
```

Though WorksheetFunctions are usualy slow.

Comment: Because `iJob` is an Excel range name, not a VBA variable, your last code line should be `MsgBox wsFunc.VLookup(txt, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("iJob"), 4, False)`

Comment: @YowE3K ops :D you're right, well, alternatively we can set **iJob** to `Range('iJob")`

Comment: Yes, you could `Set iJob = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("iJob")` if you wish, and then use the variable.

Comment: Thanks mate!. I have variety of codes to chose how I want to write. Also, thanks for the headups that WorksheetFunctions are slow. :))

Comment: Another tip would be to use `Application.VLookup` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`.  The `WorksheetFunction` will crash if a match is not found, whereas the native `Application` version will return a `Variant/Error` value which can then be tested using `If IsError(your_return_value) Then` to allow error processing.

Comment: That's the problem with SO - you end up learning so much, that you get addicted to it and you never have time to get out in the real world and live

Answer (score 1):

TRY-

```
Range("B2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$6,4,0)" 
Tab2 = Range("B2").Value
```

also you might be intersted in this- [How to use a VLOOKUP function in Excel VBA](https://www.microsofttraining.net/b/use-vlookup-function-excel-vba/)

**do it purely using VBA**

```
Sub foo()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim txt As String
Dim iJob As Range
Dim tab2 As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set iJob = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D6") ' the table ranage where to search
txt = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").value ' the lookup value

On Error Resume Next
tab2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(txt, iJob, 4, False)

MsgBox tab2 ' the search result


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Abhinav, as much as possible, I don't want to manipulate the cell in putting  the value. I just want Tab2 to hold the result of the vlookup, is this possible??
And BTW, iJob and txt are working